# Will a flask API endpoint with multiple gunicorn workers cause duplicate requests?

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I've written a Flask app that's deployed using gunicorn with 3 workers. The app exposes a REST endpoint at `/endpoints/create_parcel` that receives POST data sent to it via a form and makes an API request to a third party website. I'm noticing that occassionally it looks like the requests are duplicated. Is it possible that when my application's endpoint receives the request that is picked up by two or more workers at the precise same time, resulting in duplicate requests? If so, does anyone know a fix for this?

I'm running gunicorn like this,

```
/home/user/miniconda3/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --workers 3 --timeout 300 --chdir /home/user/app wsgi:app
```

I created an API endpoint in a flask app, and ran the flask app with three workers using gunicorn. It looks like the three workers are sometimes each receiving some requests, when I'd expect only one of them to receive each request.

Comment: Can you update with your config gunicorn?

Comment: @TanThien I've updated the post with the command I'm using to run gunicorn. I assume this is what you need, if not please let me know.